# Automating user data storage on a blockchain

Tags: blockchain, remix

I have a smart contract that contains a function to store data onto the blockchain. The function stores two integer variables to the blockchain. Now, I can manually store the values from the remix-ide but the problem is I have to store multiple values to the blockchain. Suppose the fields are First Name and Last Name, then I have to store the values, again and again, multiple times. Is there any way to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in Json or Array format, create a node app and iterate the contract calls using web3(npm package).

Check this out for reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48193611/10845790.

In above solution version of web3 used is 0.20.x

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, to me, if the OP wants to automate the writing stage or the reading stage.

These patterns might provide a few ideas: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

It's possible to group inserts into batches if the write functions use dynamic arrays for input.

Hope it helps.